# How do I remove Ubuntu and put OSX back on?

Tags: installation, mac

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my Mac OS 10.8 and I'm having some trouble getting used to it and everything. I want to make it a Mac again. How do I do that?

I've already tried to install my CD that came with the computer, but it does not work.

Comment: Did you overwrite the Mac OS partition, or did you install Ubuntu alongside Mac OS (keeping the Mac OS partition?)

Comment: "it does not work" - please describe what you have actually tried and at what point it failed from your expectations.

Answer (score 1):

Try again your mac OS install CD, but when it boots choose advanced options and repartition your drive (delete existing partitions, create one new partition with default settings). That should permit you to do a clean install.

Obviously, make a backup of your data before doing this.